# Get multiple images crops from single image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am developing an OCR which scans the text that the detector module detects, given that one image has `n` bounding boxes I want a function that reads the `.xml` that get the coordinates to crop the image arround the bounding boxes. This is what I tried:

```
def get_cropped_image(image_file, 
                  images_path = "data/split/train/images",
                  annotations_path = "data/split/train/annotations"):

    images_filenames = os.listdir(images_path)
    annotations_filenames = os.listdir(annotations_path)

    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(images_path, image_file))
    annotation_filename = image_file.split(sep='.')[0]+'.xml'


    bboxes, labels = read_annotation_file(annotations_path, annotation_filename)

    for idx, label in enumerate(labels):
        try:
            cropped_img = imcrop(image, bboxes[idx]).copy()
            return cropped_img
        except:
            raise
```

However, this function just returns the first bounding box crop from every image. How can I actually return the `n` crops from each image?

Comment: have you considered putting the cropped subimages into a list, and returning that instead? this is rather simple and should be no surprise to you, if you wrote that code already

Comment: Indeed, I already put them into a list and tried with a dictionary to map the image_id (key) to the numpy array. However, I was wondering if it is the **best** way to do it (I want to minimize the memory usage).

Comment: you didn't say any of that in the post so I'm inclined to believe you didn't think of it before the suggestions were made here.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a list of cropped images:

```
imgList = []

for idx, label in enumerate(labels):
    imgList.append(imcrop(image, bboxes[idx]).copy())

return imgList
```

Comment: If your question was actually to address concerns about memory consumption, you should have indicated that. If you change your `return` statement to `yield` then it will become a generator and return one crop on each call. Have a read here... https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/